# Passing PHP variables to JS function

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pass variables from php page to javascript and display the the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648949/how-to-pass-variables-from-php-page-to-javascript-and-display-the-the-data)

I am trying to pass PHP variables to a javascript function. I know there are many articles/questions about the issue but none of them seems to work for me. My problem is a little weird. Let me start with the code.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    $type = 'Dance';
    $environment = 'Outside';
?>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="showEvents(<?=$type ?>, <?=$environment ?>)">
        <select class="drop_down_menus" name="type">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>Dance</option>
            <option>Festival</option>
            <option>Music</option>
            <option>Stand-Up</option>
            <option>Theather</option>                               
        </select>
        <select class="drop_down_menus" name="environment">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>Indoor</option>
            <option>Outdoor</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Event Me Out!">
</form>
<div id="test_div">test1</div>
```

This is JS code:

```
function showEvents(type, environment) {
    document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = "test2";
}
```

When I click the submit button, text of the "test_div" has to change from "test1" to "test2" but nothing changes when I submit the form.

The weird thing starts here:

When I use the following PHP variable and change both of the variables to "$current_year" it works!

```
<?php
    $today = getdate();
    $current_year = $today['year'];
?>

<form onsubmit="showEvents(<?=$current_year ?>, <?=$current_year ?>)">
...rest of the HTML code...
```

I first thought it is a scope issue but obviously it is not because one variable works and others not while all had the same scope.

Maybe there is something very simple I don't know. If you can help me (or direct me to another question) I will be grateful. None of the solutions helped me so far.

Thank you in advance.

NOTE1: I tried to echo the `$type` and `$environment` variables but no help.

NOTE2: It looks like I don't use the selections in the drop down menus but I didn't write the full code in here.

Comment: you're using <?= ?> , short tags , make sure they're activated in php config file.

Comment: try to add quotes "'" to the variables like this : '<?=$type ?>'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use:

```
<form onsubmit="showEvents('<?=$type ?>', '<?=$environment ?>')">
```

You're trying to do this: `showEvents(Dance, Outside)` instead of: `showEvents('Dance', 'Outside')` but you could have more errors. For instance, `<?=$type ?>` is not recommended. You should use `<?php echo $type ?>`.

Comment: I can't believe this, I have spent days on that and now it worked. Thank you! I will accept your answer in 4 min, it doesn't let me right now. Thanks for the echo suggestion too, I changed it already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably the short tags that you have used in the code to echo the php variable ie

Please avoid using PHP short tags as they might not be enabled in all the servers. It is always a good practice to use

```
<?php echo $something ?>
```

instead of

```
<?= $something ?>
```